# Name for a property of a function

Tags: functions, terminology

Let $f: \mathcal{P}_n(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function maps a polynomial to a real number.
And it has following property for $A, B \in \mathcal{P}_n(\mathbb{R}), b \in \mathcal{P}_1(\mathbb{R})$, $\frac{A}{b} \in \mathcal{P}_{n-1}(\mathbb{R}), \frac{B}{b} \in \mathcal{P}_{n-1}(\mathbb{R})$:
$$
f(\frac{A+B}{b}) - f(\frac{B}{b}) = f(\frac{A}{b})
$$

Is there a name for this property?

Comment: $\mathcal{P}_1(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of linear polynomials? If so, $\frac{A+B}{b}$ is not necessarily a polynomial.

Comment: it is, and let's say for my purpose both $A, B$ are linear multipliers of $b$.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you could make such a function by having it be the identity on $\mathcal{P}_{n-1}(\mathbb{R})$ and do anything you like on $\mathcal{P}_{n}(\mathbb{R}) \backslash \mathcal{P}_{n-1}(\mathbb{R})$. That's a bit of a weird condition.